# Can it be bad to link against shared libraries that are not being used?

Tags: gcc, ld

Will gcc/ld really include the references to those shared libraries on the final executable, even if there's no reference to any function from those? If so, is there any potential problems that I may face by doing something like that?

Answer (score 1):

Look at this test:

If you have

```
//file.c
int main(){
   return 1;
}
```

And compile

```
gcc file.c -lm
```

Then

```
$ ldd a.out 
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff3ece6000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f1898e59000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f1899269000)
```

No link to mathlib

The issues you may have are larger linking times and the risk of an accidental symbol collision.

Comment: The result you observe is only true on Ubuntu (which includes strange patches), please at least specify that...

Comment: Could somebody confirm this? I think that behaviour is default on linking ELF binaries, but I don't have a non debian based machine at hand. Of course, linking for other archs, like  embedded baremetal, will behave different.

Comment: Debian behaves differently from Ubuntu here, so "debian based" is not the right criterion.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to linkage times and possible symbol conflicts cited by @xvan, if you happen to build packages (such as RPMs), those extra linkages result in unnecessary dependencies, which result in extra packages being installed on the target system.

Further reading:

- [Automatic Dependencies](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-depend-auto-depend.html) (Maximum RPM: Taking the Red Hat Package Manager to the Limit)
- [Re: using "--nodeps" with rpmbuild is it possible?](https://www.redhat.com/archives/rpm-list/2007-September/msg00058.html)